# How to get the compressed image data from JPEG encoder in Java

Tags: java, io, jpeg, codec

I want to compress an image using JPEG encoder and instead of writing it to a file I want to pass the compressed data to another application. My problem is that I can compress the data but don't know how to get that compressed image data. I am using this code :

```
 out = new FileOutputStream ( filename );
 JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder ( out );
 JPEGEncodeParam param = encoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam ( bi );
 param.setQuality ( 0.3f, false );  
 encoder.setJPEGEncodeParam ( param );
 encoder.encode ( bi );
 out.close();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) will give you access to the bytes.

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream (  );
 JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder ( out );
 JPEGEncodeParam param = encoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam ( bi);
 param.setQuality ( 0.3f, false );  
 encoder.setJPEGEncodeParam ( param );
 encoder.encode (bi);
 out.close(); // a no-op on ByteArrayOutputStream
 byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of a `FileOutputStream`. Then, you can get the bytes via `toByteArray()`.